# Adobe brackets is not installing on lunix

Tags: libcurl, adobe-brackets

I am using kali lunix 2018 and i try to install brackets but it is NOT installing in lunix 
It always say that brackets depend on libcurl3 but it is not going to install 
And libcurl3 is also not installing on my system
As libcurl4 is already installed